# Can't use cd command or execute a file as root

Tags: command-line, root

I'd like to upgrade my BIOS  I have the files and the instruction here its
"This script requires root level permissions and 
    should only be run on HP Laptops with Linux Preinstalled.

1. Switch to super user(root)
2. Make sure the gzip(.gz) file is in the same directory with the script.
3. Change the permissions on the file hp-linux-bios-installer to make it executable with:

   ```
   chmod +x hp-linux-bios-installer
   ```
4. Execute the installer by typing the following command:

   ```
   ./hp-linux-bios-installer
   ```
5. Reboot to the BIOS menu by pressing F10 at the HP Splash screen and 
   check the "Update System Bios" checkbox
6. Press ESC
7. Save changes
8. Once, unit reboots, press the "Apply Update Now" button at the HP BIOS Update screen
9. Boot back into BIOS Screen and click "Restore Defaults"
10. Press ESC
11. Save changes."

I did the first three steps put when I switch to root ... I can not execute the script or I can not change the dir to Desktop so I can execute it (the folder is on my Desktop - do I have to move it somewhere else?)

Comment: Did you do `sudo -i`? This puts you in root's home directory so you have to `cd /home/username/Desktop` (use your own username)

Comment: yes I did and after I try to execute the file I got this message : -bash: ./hp-linux-bios-installer: No such file or directory

Comment: I can not use cd on root mode

Comment: While still in the same directory as the installer, did you do this on the file - `chmod +x hp-linux-bios-installer` ?

Comment: yes but not on root mode

Comment: you can use `cd`. What error does it give you? The shell prompt will change. Open the shell `sudo -i`, type `cd ..` then `cd home` then `cd [your username]` then `cd Desktop`

Comment: @Sami - Does it still not work?

Comment: @Raphael Sami would get a different error if the file were not executable, I believe. That isn't the problem... the file isn't in the working directory...

Comment: I got it thank you so much man I appreciate it

Comment: I will write it as an answer :)

Comment: Why are you using `sudo -i` to switch to root? what prevented you using `sudo ./hp-linux-bios-installer`?

Comment: @AnwarShah: The OP is following the manufacturer's instructions.

Answer (score 7):

As pointed out by @AnwarShah you could (and should) just run the script with `sudo`

```
sudo ./hp-linux-bios-installer
```

But here is what went wrong:

You put the `.gzip` file and the `hp-linux-bios-installer` in your ~/Desktop directory. You made the file `hp-linux-bios-installer` executable...

Then you do `sudo -i`

Whatever the current working directory is, when you open a shell as root with this command, you are now in root's home directory `/root`. Type `pwd` and you will see this.

**Tilde expansion** is performed in reference to the *current user*, so if you try to do

```
cd Desktop
cd ~/Desktop
```

neither of them will work because there is no directory `/root/Desktop` (and if there were it wouldn't be the one you want). You can use the full path

```
cd /home/YOUR_USERNAME/Desktop/DIRECTORY-NAME
```

or go in steps, (use `ls` and `pwd` if you get lost) (I use my own username as an example here)

```
cd ..
cd home
cd zanna
cd Desktop
cd [directory-name-with-the-files]
```

Now you can run the executable in this directory.

Comment: `sudo ./hp-linux-bios-installer` should also work without switching to root and it should be first try and thus promoted. You can include this suggestion too

Comment: @AnwarShah good point!